# Is there a generic hierarchical difference in measure theory between $\LaTeX$ \mathcal and \mathscr?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I am wondering abut $\mathcal F$ perhaps denoting a $\sigma$-algebra, whereas $\mathscr F$ may be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, or a set of sigma algebras.

Also, if there a standardized, or tacit understanding that $\mathscr F$ is more important, or bigger in cardinality than $\mathcal F$, is that a problem when hand-writing mathematics?

Comment: I write an arbitrary sigma algebra as $\mathfrak{M}$ or $\Sigma$, and Borel algebra as $\mathscr{B}_X$ where $X$ is a topological space. I think these notations are quite standard.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, no.  The choice of whether to use `cal` or `scr` is generally just stylistic.  I don't think I've ever seen $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ both appearing in the same paper; authors (or their typesetters) choose one or the other.  They don't use both to refer to two different objects.

Comment: With a touch of remorse for my mathematical promiscuity, let me disclose the origin of the question: it's about the use of both commands in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1773465/152225).

Comment: This is not directly related to this question, but I have seen some probability papers which use all the symbols $C, \mathcal{C}, \mathscr{C}$, and even worse, all the symbols $\Bbb{P}, P, \mathbf{P}, \mathsf{P}$ for appropriate probability laws.